# Session handling with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added a notification with css fixed sticky footer and it's included in every page so wherever a user lands they will get the notification, and using jquery users can hide it.

The problem is, every time the same user browse through another page or refresh the page, they will get that message again and again. It's a bit annoying even for me.

I don't use server side scripting, so no session, and it's just a simple notification message and using jquery plugin I think it costs too much, I only have HTML, CSS and Javascript, is there a way it can be done using three of them?

Comment: Use cookies to store the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using only the client side, then you might use the browser local storage or cookies.

By using the local storage you will define and save a value if the user hasn't already visited the page, and show the notification, otherwise delete the values already set.

The same can be applied on cookies too. It all depends which one you want to use.

Here are some good references:

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 0):

You can store a cookie and check it later:

```
$.cookie('foo', 'bar');
$.cookie('foo');
```

Or you can also use localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
localStorage.getItem('foo');
```